# Can't create a user cookie in JSP

Tags: jsp, cookies

I have a login Jsp page, and when the login sucesses , I wan't to create a cookie on the admin machine.

I wrote this code:

```
<%@page import="entities.LastLogin"%>
<%@page import="implementations.LastLoginManager"%>
<%@page import="implementations.Users"%>
<%@page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<%

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    if(username == null || password == null) return;

    Users um = Users.getInstance();
    if(um.authenticateLogin(username, password)) {
        LastLogin thisLogin = new LastLogin(0, username, request.getHeader("User-Agent")); // log the last login
        LastLoginManager.getInstance().updateLastLogin(thisLogin); // save last login

        // login sucessfull so create a admin cookie
        Cookie newCookie = new Cookie("admin", username);
        newCookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24);
        response.addCookie(newCookie);
        out.print("OK");
    } else {
        out.println("Username or password are incorrect");
    }
%>
```

every time `OK` returned, no cookie has been created.

I remember that when I programmed in PHP, I had to write the cookie declaration in the first line (right after `<?php`). not sure if this is the same problem here, but if so, how can I do it? I need to verify the login before I create the cookie.

I know there is a serious security issue here, but it's not a real site, I'm just learning JSP.

How to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you missed 'path' of the cookie. Just set newCookie.setPath("/") and test.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.